# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to define a constructor for my class, but it gives me the following error ...

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'MyCotroller' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching
> constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple
> parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Somebody can help me?

servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="myCotroller" class="es.spring.conexion.MyCotroller">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" type="String" value="${url}"  />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" type="String" value="${port}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" type="String" value="${base}" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="3" type="String" value="${userAdmin}" />
</beans:bean>
```

MyCotroller.java

```
public class MyCotroller implements IMyCotroller {

private String url; 
private String puerto; 
private String base;
private String adminUser;

public MyCotroller(String url, String port, String base, String userAdmin) {
    this.url = url;
    this.puerto = puerto;
    this.base = base;
    this.adminUser =adminUser;
}
```

}

Comment: Your type should be `java.lang.String` not just `String`. Also make sure you aren't using component-scanning for this bean as well. That being said the error doesn't match your configuration you posted so I wonder if you are using other means of configuring as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
<beans:bean id="myCotroller" class="es.spring.conexion.MyCotroller">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${url}"  />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" type="java.lang.String" value="${base}" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="3" type="java.lang.String" value="${userAdmin}" />
</beans:bean>
```